# Add custom menu entries to tinymce

Tags: tinymce, impresspages

I want to add a custom menu to tinymce. I just want to press a sub element and insert text. How can I do that?

I want to do that through a plugin.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this directly via the TinyMCE configuration object (no need for a plugin).  You can add a `setup` function in the configuration object and then add either a toolbar button or menu item to do what you want.

**Setup Function**
The TinyMCE configuration object can have a setup function where you can add functionality to the editor.  It is a simple function:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',  // change this value according to your HTML
  .
  .
  .
  setup: function (editor) {
    //Your setup code here... 
  }
});
```

You can then add either a toolbar button or menu item via that setup function as described below.

**Toolbar Button Example:**

```
setup: function (editor) {
    editor.addButton('customButton', {
        text: 'My Custom Button',
        context: 'tags',
        onclick: function () { 
            editor.insertContent('content to insert goes here');
        }
    });
}
```

*Don't forget to add this button to a toolbar in the TinyMCE configuration.*

**Menu Example**

```
setup: function (editor) {
    editor.addMenuItem('custommenuitem', {
        text: 'Text for Menu Item', 
        context: 'insert',
        onclick: function () { 
            editor.insertContent('content to insert goes here');
        }
    });
}
```

*This will now appear in the Insert menu (based on the context setting)*

Comment: If you want a top level menu of your own (as opposed to placing your button in an existing menu) you can do this:  https://www.tinymce.com/docs/demo/custom-toolbar-menu-button/

Comment: how can i do that via an impress pages plugin?

Comment: also, I think impress pages use tinymce 3

Comment: The Impress Pages demo site uses TinyMCE 4.1.6 at least the current version is not using TinyMCE 3.  As for making an Impress Pages plugin - I have no idea as I have no experience with that tool.  Perhaps you can ask that via Impress Pages support?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example plugin, that modify TinyMCE http://market.impresspages.org/plugins/JustifyAlign

There are more TinyMCE related plugins to take as example http://market.impresspages.org/plugins

Comment: I know that. The problem is HOW I'm gonna modify tinymce toolbar trough an impress pages plugin to add a menu. The answer tha Michael left requires me to change the setup function, so I'll have to alter the core files.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to read up the ImpressPages plugin documentation to understand how to create a plugin https://www.impresspages.org/docs/plugin.

You'll get to the part where you add an assets folder where you'll place a tinymce config file

like this one:

```
var originalConfigFunction = ipcustomMceConfig;

var ipcustomMceConfig = function () {
var originalConfig = originalConfigFunction();



return originalConfig;
}

var Custom = ipcustomMceConfig;
var ipcustomMceConfig = function () {
var originalConfig = Custom();
originalConfig.toolbar2 = originalConfig.toolbar2 + ' example ';
originalConfig.external_example_path = ip.baseUrl + 'Plugin/example/';


if (!originalConfig.external_plugins) {
    originalConfig.external_plugins = {};
}
originalConfig.external_plugins.example = ip.baseUrl + 'Plugin/Custom/assets/example/plugin.min.js';
originalConfig.content_css = 'url/sample/css';
originalConfig.extended_valid_element = 'span[class]';

return originalConfig;

}
```

That's how you add an element to the toolbar as a plugin. Notice the ip.baseUrl which is very important for you to keep it dynamic avoid using hard coded paths.

Look at this plugin for example https://github.com/impresspages-plugins/TinyMceFileBrowser, once you go through the structure and each file in it you'll get a good grasp.